# Funcion Ajax no lee el archivo descrito en url

Tags: php, ajax, apache

Estimados tengo el siguiente inconveniente, estoy trabajando de forma local con wampserver y esoty tratando de replicar la estrucutura de archivos de mi pagina web para no tener probemas en las rutas a la hora de subir la pagina al servidor real.

en la carpeta wamp64/www tengo mi proyecto llamado ecuservi. Dentro de dicha carpeta tengo public_html donde se enmcuentra todo el contenido html de mi web. y la carpeta logica donde se encuentran todas las funciones php.

Tengo un alias creado de la siguiente forma

Alias /ecuservi "C:\wamp64\www\ecuservi\public_html"

```
<Directory "C:\wamp64\www\ecuservi/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
  AllowOverride all
  <ifDefine APACHE24>
        #Require local
        Require all granted
    </ifDefine>
    <ifDefine !APACHE24>
        Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from localhost ::1 127.0.0.1
    </ifDefine>
</Directory>
```

En el caso de prueba me encuentro en localhost/ecuservi/portal/login.
Si directamente con php hago un

```
include '../../../logica/login.php'
```

para salirme de la carpeta public_html y acceder a logica los archivos si son leidos.

Përo si la ruta la pongo de la misma forma en una funcion ajax, no me la reconoce y meda error 404 con dicha ruta.

```
//MOSTRAR REGIONES//
    function listado_regiones(){     
        var action = 'fetch_data';          
        $.ajax({        
            url:"../../../logica/listado_regiones.php", 
            method: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data:{ action:action},        
            success:function(data){
                $('.input_region').html(data.html1);        
                $('#region').change(function(){
                    var $this = $(this), label = $this.prev("label");       
                    if($this.val() === "") {
                        label.removeClass("active"); 
                    }else{
                        label.addClass("active"); 
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

Como puedo acceder de forma correcta a dicha url para despues no tener problemas en el servidor

Adjunto imagenes

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El archivo con la funcion ajax se encuentra dentro de portal/login/index.php
Y el archivos listado_regiones.php se encuentra en la carpeta /logica

Comment: Lo más importante aquí es conocer tu estructura de archivos. Comparte una carpeta o una estructura de árbol donde se pueda ver en qué carpeta está el archivo Ajax y en qué carpeta está el archivo `listado_regiones.php`

Comment: Pregunta editada la funcion ajax se encuentra en el mismo codigo html insertado como script.

Comment: Por lo que se ve en la captura, `logica` se encuentra al mismo nivel que `public_html` y supongo que `portal` está dentro de `public_html` ¿Es correcto? Eso no queda claro.

Comment: Si correcto, portal esta dentro de public_html

Comment: El problema aquí es que `logica` está fuera de tu directorio `public_html` entonces, desde el cliente (Javascript) no puedes acceder como lo haces sin problema desde el servidor, en cuyo caso sí funciona como dices.  Podrías acceder, quizá, poniendo la ruta absoluta, algo así: `home/logica/listado_regiones.php`  pero eso, si es que funciona, es una pésima práctica que rompe totalmente el sentido del directorio `public_html` en el cual deberías incluir todos aquellos scripts a los que quieras acceder desde el cliente.

Comment: Lo único que hay en la carpeta lógica son funciones php, para consultas en bases de datos, todo lo que son scripts.js estan en la carpeta public_html, necesito replicar esto en forma local, por eso no me sirve poner la ruta home/lógica como tu me mencionas

Comment: No sé a qué te refieres con que necesitas replicarlo en forma local. El criterio que debe quedar claro es que: **cualquier script, sea `.php` u otro, al que tengas que acceder desde el cliente, debe ir dentro de la carpeta `public_html`**. Ese es el sentido de esa carpeta. ¿Cuál es el motivo para tener a `logica` fuera de `public_html`?

Comment: por motivos de seguridad estoy dejando los scipt php fuera de public_html, digo que quiero replicar de forma local, porque aun no subo la pagina al servidor

Comment: Precisamente, sería menos seguro permitir acceso desde el cliente a carpetas que están fuera de `public_html` Si esos archivos fueran a ser accedidos sólo desde el servidor no hay ningún problema, pero como quieres acceder a ellos desde el cliente también debes ponerlos en `public_html` De todos modos, los archivos `.php`  son seguros, el cliente sólo puede llamarlos para ejecutar lo que el archivo deba hacer, por tanto si ese archivo está bien escrito (por ejemplo las consultas SQL, se filtran las entradas, etc) no hay ningún problema.